# Unexpected behavior when extracting minima using turnpoints (Pastecs package in R)

Tags: r

I have some data, height.

```
> print(height)
             V3          V4          V5          V6          V7          V8          V9         V10         V11         V12         V13         V14         V15 
      0.0000000  -3.1486232  39.1502937  -2.8437808 -24.7633269 -35.4022061 -36.2401943  46.4133021 -19.1868097   0.4067331  22.6768200 -38.8550971 -41.3161054 
            V16         V17         V18         V19         V20 
     33.0446273  41.4934899  19.9558741   3.3477473   0.3611974
```

I then apply turnpoints(), and use extract() to get what looks like a logical vector indicating the positions of the minima.

```
tp = turnpoints(height)
pitpositions = extract(tp, peak = FALSE, pit = TRUE)
print(pitpositions) # [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

I would expect that `height[pitpositions]` would give the values of the minima, and that `height[!pitpositions]` would give the values of the non-minima.

The latter works as expected:

```
> height[!pitpositions]
         V3          V5          V6          V7          V8         V10         V12         V13         V14         V16         V17         V18         V19 
  0.0000000  39.1502937  -2.8437808 -24.7633269 -35.4022061  46.4133021   0.4067331  22.6768200 -38.8550971  33.0446273  41.4934899  19.9558741   3.3477473 
        V20 
  0.3611974
```

But the former doesn't, and I don't know how to interpret the results:

```
> height[pitpositions]
V3 V3 V3 V3 
 0  0  0  0
```

So my questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I get the result that I'm looking for (basically the opposite of height[!pitpositions]?

Edit:

To answer question number 2, I can get what I'm looking for using `height[tp$pits]`.  tp$pits seems to have the same information as `pitpositions`, but when I print out `pitpositoins` I get a series of `TRUE` `FALSE`, whereas when I print out `tp$pits` I get a series of `0 1`.  I would have thought these were equivalent, as `0 == FALSE` and `1 == TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `extract` is doing what you want. It's serendipitous that height[!pitpositions] is giving something you like.

I'd recommend something more like just using the components of `tp` directly.

```
Rgames> tp$peaks
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Rgames> tp$pits
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Rgames> height[tp$peaks]
[1] 39.15029 46.41330 22.67682 41.49349
Rgames> height[tp$pits]
[1]  -3.148623 -36.240194 -19.186810 -41.316105
```

EDIT:  it appears that the default method for `extract` on a `turnpoints` object is:

```
Rgames> extract(tp)
 [1]  0 -1  1  0  0  0 -1  1 -1  0  1  0 -1  0  1  0  0  0
```

So, rather than extracting a subset of that, you would probably want to do something like

```
height[extract(tp)== -1]
```

for pits, and

```
height[extract(tp)== 1]
```

for peaks. I suspect your original `extract` formula as posted returns all values not equal to 1  (or not equal to -1), hence the zeroes, and the change in length of the vector.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that's doing exactly what I need.  Can you give an example of when one would use extract()?